# Prevent download of files from Notes in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016, security-roles

Is it possible to prevent the download of a file in the Notes section of some forms, depending on the user's role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. To implement that you can use Plugins or Real-Time workflows. Following article describes how to check if user has role or not - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602961.aspx

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. In fact the requirement is to prevent some users from downloading (not uploading, sorry) the file that is present in the Notes section of a form. Personally I don't understand how this could be possible with a plugin (what would be the entity, and the plugin registration message?)

Comment: In download case you still can try plugin - Annotation entity and Retrieve message. Good luck.

Comment: I really don't understand how I can use the Retrieve message in a plugin to prevent the download of a file whose download link is in the Notes area. Maybe in this way I can prevent the user from seeing the whole notes area, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: So the idea behind is following - without complete removal of permissions you can't disallow users to see download link. What you can do with a plugin is detect that user clicked Download button - because Retrieve message has to be called, check if user allowed or not to download attachment and throw an exception that will prevent download.

Comment: I am also looking for same functionality, Can you please explain me how can i remove download link as file is downloading when selecting Title of Note name

Comment: @Raju suggested approach doesn't hide download link. It just throws an exception when user tries to download file.